# Domain of functional sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

may I ask you about domain of this functional sequence?

functional sequence is ln(1/n - x)

n is natural number from 1

I dont know if it is (-inf;0) or (-inf;0].

thanks a lot :)

Comment: Why are you interested in this question and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=\ln\left(\frac1n-x\right)$ and see whether $f_n(0)$ makes sense for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Formally $f_n(0)=\ln\left(\frac1n\right)$; is that defined for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$?

Comment: Yes, it is defined for all n, so the domain is (-inf;0], right? :)

Comment: @naruto25: Yes, that’s right.